# Zend 1 not working with psr-4 namespaces

Tags: php, zend-framework, psr-4

I am working on zend framework 1 But I want to use \ instead of _

Like

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
```

This is working fine but when I changed this by

```
class IndexController extends \Zend\Controller\Action
```

Then its giving me a error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_Controller_Action in /var/www/flipit_application/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php on line 43
```

I have created the namespaces in composer

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Zend\\": "vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/"
        }
    },
```

So how Can use these namespaces in code

**Is this possible in Zend Framework1?.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework 1 doesn't use psr-4 autoloading, it uses psr-0:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Zend_": "vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library"
    }
}
```